# Spring Boot 3.0.1, Spring Data Jpa 3.0.1 e Specification - Consulta sem os parametros mesmo especificados

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, jpa-2.0, spring-jpa

Estou fazendo uma pesquisa passando parametros utilizando o especification do JPA, porem a consulta `findAll` executa retornando toda a listagem sem filtrar pelos parametros.
o interessante é que se eu usar o Spring Boot 2.7.4 funciona perfeitamente da maneira que vou enviar aqui, porém preciso usar o Spring Boot e Spring Data JPA 3.0.1.

Segue o projeto:

**Pom.xml**

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.rader</groupId>
    <artifactId>algafood-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>algafood-api</name>
    <description>API de delivery de comida</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
        <dockerfile-maven-version>1.4.13</dockerfile-maven-version>
        <modelmapper.version>3.1.0</modelmapper.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <!-- Starters -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Ferramentas -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Banco de dados e JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Flyway -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-mysql</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--Testes -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Model Mapper-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>${modelmapper.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>docker</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                        <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${dockerfile-maven-version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>default</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build</goal>
                                    <goal>push</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <repository>algafood-api</repository>
                            <buildArgs>
                                <JAR_FILE>${project.build.finalName}.jar</JAR_FILE>
                            </buildArgs>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

**Classe Model**

```java
@Setter
@Getter
public class PedidoResumoModel {

    private String codigo;
    private BigDecimal subtotal;
    private BigDecimal taxaFrete;
    private BigDecimal valorTotal;
    private String status;
    private OffsetDateTime dataCriacao;
    private RestauranteResumoModel restaurante;
    private UsuarioModel cliente;

}
```

Controlller
**PedidoController.java**

```java
 @GetMapping
    public List<PedidoResumoModel> pesquisar(PedidoFilter filtro) {
        List<Pedido> todosPedidos = pedidoRepository.findAll(PedidoSpecs.usandoFiltro(filtro));

        return pedidoResumoModelAssembler.toCollectionModel(todosPedidos);
    }
```

**PedidoSpecs.java**

```java
ublic class PedidoSpecs {

    public static Specification<Pedido> usandoFiltro(PedidoFilter filtro) {
        return (root, query, builder) -> {
            root.fetch("restaurante").fetch("cozinha");
            root.fetch("cliente");

            var predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

            if (filtro.getClienteId() != null) {
                predicates.add(builder.equal(root.get("cliente"), filtro.getClienteId()));
            }

            if (filtro.getRestauranteId() != null) {
                predicates.add(builder.equal(root.get("restaurante"), filtro.getRestauranteId()));
            }

            if (filtro.getDataCriacaoInicio() != null) {
                predicates.add(builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("dataCriacao"),
                        filtro.getDataCriacaoInicio()));
            }

            if (filtro.getDataCriacaoFim() != null) {
                predicates.add(builder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("dataCriacao"),
                        filtro.getDataCriacaoFim()));
            }

            return builder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
        };
    }

}
```

**Repositorio**

```java
@Repository
public interface PedidoRepository extends JpaSpecificationExecutor<Pedido>, CustomJpaRepository<Pedido, Long>{

    Optional<Pedido> findByCodigo(String codigo);

    @Query("from Pedido p join fetch p.cliente join fetch p.restaurante r join fetch r.cozinha")
    List<Pedido> findAll(Specification<Pedido> spec);

}
```

Requisiçao:
`GET` - `/pedidos?clienteId=2&restauranteId=2`

[Imagem do Postman com a requisiçao](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4qsg.png)

e retorna a lista completa sem o filtro

```js
[
    {
        "codigo": "f9981ca4-5a5e-4da3-af04-933861df3e55",
        "subtotal": 298.90,
        "taxaFrete": 10.00,
        "valorTotal": 308.90,
        "status": "CRIADO",
        "dataCriacao": "2023-01-30T06:34:21Z",
        "restaurante": {
            "id": 1,
            "nome": "Thai Gourmet"
        },
        "cliente": {
            "id": 1,
            "nome": "João da Silva",
            "email": "joao.ger@algafood.com"
        }
    },
    {
        "codigo": "d178b637-a785-4768-a3cb-aa1ce5a8cdab",
        "subtotal": 79.00,
        "taxaFrete": 0.00,
        "valorTotal": 79.00,
        "status": "CRIADO",
        "dataCriacao": "2023-01-30T06:34:21Z",
        "restaurante": {
            "id": 4,
            "nome": "Java Steakhouse"
        },
        "cliente": {
            "id": 1,
            "nome": "João da Silva",
            "email": "joao.ger@algafood.com"
        }
    },
    {
        "codigo": "b5741512-8fbc-47fa-9ac1-b530354fc0ff",
        "subtotal": 110.00,
        "taxaFrete": 10.00,
        "valorTotal": 120.00,
        "status": "ENTREGUE",
        "dataCriacao": "2019-10-30T21:10:00Z",
        "restaurante": {
            "id": 1,
            "nome": "Thai Gourmet"
        },
        "cliente": {
            "id": 1,
            "nome": "João da Silva",
            "email": "joao.ger@algafood.com"
        }
    },
    {
        "codigo": "5c621c9a-ba61-4454-8631-8aabefe58dc2",
        "subtotal": 174.40,
        "taxaFrete": 5.00,
        "valorTotal": 179.40,
        "status": "ENTREGUE",
        "dataCriacao": "2019-11-02T20:34:04Z",
        "restaurante": {
            "id": 1,
            "nome": "Thai Gourmet"
        },
        "cliente": {
            "id": 2,
            "nome": "Maria Joaquina",
            "email": "maria.vnd@algafood.com"
        }
    },
    {
        "codigo": "8d774bcf-b238-42f3-aef1-5fb388754d63",
        "subtotal": 87.20,
        "taxaFrete": 10.00,
        "valorTotal": 97.20,
        "status": "ENTREGUE",
        "dataCriacao": "2019-11-02T21:00:30Z",
        "restaurante": {
            "id": 1,
            "nome": "Thai Gourmet"
        },
        "cliente": {
            "id": 3,
            "nome": "José Souza",
            "email": "jose.aux@algafood.com"
        }
    }
]
```

*Segue o link do repositório do código de toda a implementaçao:*

https://github.com/raderleao/fastfood-api.git

Answer (score 0):

O problema ai era que no javax eu conseguia fazer uma comparação dessa forma e com a atualização do jakarta precisei mudar como segue:

```
    public static Specification<Pedido> usandoFiltro(PedidoFilter filtro) {
        return (root, query, builder) -> {
            if (Pedido.class.equals(query.getResultType())) {
                root.fetch("restaurante").fetch("cozinha");
                root.fetch("cliente");
            }

            var predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

            if (filtro.getClienteId() != null) {
                predicates.add(builder.equal(root.get("cliente"), filtro.getClienteId()));
            }
        return builder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
        };
    }
```

Antes no javax:

```
predicates.add(builder.equal(root.get("cliente"), filtro.getClienteId()));
```

ajustado com jakarta:

```
predicates.add(builder.equal(root.get("cliente").get("id"), filtro.getClienteId()));
```

dessa forma rodou de boa.